# Error Decoding Date with Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

For example my JSON looks like so:

```
{ 
   createdAt = "2018-06-13T12:38:22.987Z"  
}
```

My Struct looks like so:

```
struct myStruct {
    let createdAt: Date
}
```

Decode like so:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
```

When I am decoding I get this error:

> failed to decode, dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath:
>   [CodingKeys(stringValue: "results", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: 
>   "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "createdAt", intValue: 
>   nil)], debugDescription: "Expected date string to be ISO8601-formatted.", 
>   underlyingError: nil))

I understand it says that the string was expected to be ISO8601 formatted, but isn't it?

Comment: The standard ISO8601 format doesn't include milliseconds.

Comment: @rmaddy I see, is there a workaround for this?

Comment: `JSONDecoder` includes the option to provide a custom `DateFormatter` object. Create a custom DateFormatter with the desired format. Use your sample date string to test it, and then install it in the `JSONDecoder`.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/46538676/2303865

Comment: @farhan note that it is Swift naming convention to name your structures starting with an uppercase letter you might also be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46458487/how-to-convert-a-date-string-with-optional-fractional-seconds-using-codable-in-s

Answer (score 13):

The standard ISO8601 date format doesn't include fractional seconds so you need to use a custom date formatter for the date decoding strategy.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(dateFormatter)
```

Comment: You're nicer than I was going to be. :) I was going to make the OP do the legwork for himself.

Comment: That has nothing to do with your question. You don't need to format the date to a string until you are going to display it to the user.

Comment: ah this makes sense! Thanks :OP: please mark this as answered :D